# Jplayer with BackboneJS not loading flash backup

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, internet-explorer-7, jplayer

I have been stuck on this problem for days. I am trying to get jplayer + backbonejs to work in IE 5,7,8 with the flash backkup. I have setup a sample which is working correctly that has jPlayer by itself: http://www.sixthpoint.com/test/ and it correctly loads the flash backup.

However, when I combine it with Backbonejs I can't get it to load the flash object even though the inspector is showing the flash backup is loaded correctly.

Problem page: http://demo.irdb.fm/
problem script: http://demo.irdb.fm/theme/Demo/js/script.js

If anybody could get me some guidance on what could be the problem it would be much apperciated. I am loading jPlayer defaults on line 139 of the script.js

Comment: it doesn't seems like your swfPath ("http://www.irdb.fm/theme/Ksdb/js" ) exists, cab you please verify

Comment: jPlayer documentation says to put it to that directory and it will look for jPlayer.swf file. I will adjust it to have /js/jPlayer.swf to show it still won't work with the absolute url

Comment: updated the path, it still will throw the error message from jPlayer in IE 6,7,8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason, but if you simply rename `audio-player` to anything, even `audio-layer` the code will work as expected

Comment: wow, this is very odd. Do you have any thoughts / guesses on to why this would be so?